# Scene2d TextButton strange onclick behaviour

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

The textbutton in question is reused throughout the process. When on clicked it is supposed to be responded once, and only once, setting the flag "nextQuestion", which in turn will lead up to calling the method createButton().

Instead of firing once createButton(), it now fires twice or more sometimes.

I 've marked by comment in the code below the problematic onclicklistener, which actually resides as an anonymous class inside the createButton(). That probably is the problem for when a new set of buttons are created at the same position as the previous ones, the onclick event isn't gone yet, and the new ones get clicked again and then set flag and createButton() get called again.

```
private void initWordlist() {
    wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    wordList.add("Nyumba za kijiji hiki si za mawe!");
    wordList.add("nyumba/humba");
    wordList.add("ya/za");
    wordList.add("mji/kijiji");
    wordList.add("yake/hiki");
    wordList.add("ni sa udongo/si sa mawe");
}


private void createAnswerButtons() {
    nextChoices = false;

    if (questionNum > wordList.size())
        return;
    String s = wordList.get(questionNum);
    String[] choices = s.split("/");    
    int wordLength; 
    int numOfChoices = choices.length;          

    for (int i=0; i<numOfChoices ; i++)            
    {
        wordLength = choices[i].length();           
        buttons.get(i).setText(choices[i]);
        buttons.get(i).setPosition( 30 + i*150, app.camera.viewportHeight - 200);
        buttons.get(i).setSize(wordLength*10 + 50, 50);
        buttons.get(i).addListener(new ClickListener()  {

            //** the problem: this onClickListner fires more than once

            @Override 
            public void clicked(InputEvent e, float x, float y) {
                questionNum++;
                showSentence();
                nextChoices = true;
                System.out.println("Clicked, questionNum:" + questionNum);
                waiting = true;
            }
       });
       stage.addActor(buttons.get(i));
    }

}

private void update(float delta) {
    stage.act(delta);
    //System.out.println("stage.act()");
    if (nextChoices == true){
        createAnswerButtons();
    }
}
```

How to solve this one?

Comment: Not sure if you still need an answer here, but from which method is createAnswerButtons() called? If is from render? Additionally if the problem is indeed caused by creating multiple buttons in the same place it should be easy to confirm by debugging - check if clicked method is called multiple times for the same object or different objects.